# Request Clarification of Ambiguous Probability Question

Tags: probability

I'm writing to see if someone can make sense of the statement below in bold that appears in the following probability question:

"Company A has just developed a diagnostic test for a certain disease.  The disease affects 1% of the population.  The sensitivity of the test is the probability of someone testing positive, given that he/she has the disease, $P(+| D)$, and the specificity of the test is the probability that someone tests negative, given that he/she does not have the disease, $P(-|D^{c})$.  Assume the sensitivity and specificity are both 95%.

Company B, which is a rival of Company A, offers a competing test for the disease.  Company B claims that their test is faster and less expensive to perform that the test from Company A, is less painful, and yet has a higher overall success rate, where the overall success rate is defined as the probability that randomly selected person is diagnosed correctly.

The test from Company B can be described and performed very simply:$\textbf{no matter who the patient is, diagnose that he or she does not have the disease}$.Check to whether the claim of Company B about overall success rates is true.

1) Compute $P(D|+)$ and $P(D^{c}|-)$ for Company A.

2) Compute $P(D|+)$ and $P(D^{c}|-)$ for Company B.

3) Compare"

I can do 1) using Bayes and the given probabilities. But I can't figure out what the bolded statement means. Does it mean that Company B's test produces a negative diagnosis for every patient? In that case, is $P(-|D^{C}) = P(-|D) = 1$ and $P(+|D^{C})= P(+|D) = 0$?  I can't imagine this is the case, since it would result in $P(D|+) = 0$.

If anyone can shed some light on this question, I'd sure appreciate it!

Comment: How did you get $P(D|+) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means, that Company B tests negative on every patient. Their success rate is $99 \%$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The test from Company B can be described and performed very simply:
>   **no matter who the patient is, diagnose that he or she does not have the disease**.

*Yeeash.*   It appears to be claiming that their test is always negative independent of whether the subject has the disease or not.$$\mathsf P(B^+)~=~\mathsf P(B^+\mid D) ~=~\mathsf P(B^+\mid D^\complement)~=~0\\ \mathsf P(B^-)~=~ \mathsf P(B^-\mid D)~=~\mathsf P(B^-\mid D^\complement)~=~1$$

So $\mathsf P(D^\complement\mid B^-)~{=~ \mathsf P(D^\complement)\mathsf P(B^-\mid D^\complement)\div\mathsf P(B^-)\\[1ex]=~\mathsf P(D^\complement)}$

However $\mathsf P(D\mid B^+)$ is technically undefined, although you could argue that by independence it *should* be $\mathsf P(D\mid B^+)=\mathsf P(D)$.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments!  Glad to know there's a consensus around my interpretation, and that at least one person thinks the wording of that phrase was a bit wonky.